# Is there a way to rsync files to a remote location that doesn't have rsync installed?

Tags: ftp, ssh, rsync

From what I read, rsync has to be installed in both places, but I was wondering if anyone has seen a hack or workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've bumped into this situation some months ago.
There was a range of HP-UX servers where we I was forbidden to install software.
So I deployed the rsync binaries in an unpriviledged user $HOME/rsync.

From then on, you just have to specify the following flag when calling rsync to tell it where the custom remote binary is,

```
--rsync-path=
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: Hey, do you know what files I'll need for that exactly? I think it's just two files, right? Based on the Arch Linux package, I see `usr/bin/rsync` and `usr/lib/rsync/rrsync`. Is that all I need? What about config files like `etc/rsyncd.conf`? Do I need those?

Comment: Never used Arch Linux, for the HPUX boxes the files were: libiconv.sl libintl.sl  libpopt.sl and the core and rsync binaries.
No, you don't need rsync.conf except if you're expecting using it as a daemon.